# Why does Angular app built with Angular CLI give security warning on github, how do I resolve?

Tags: angular, security, github, lodash

I've built two different Angular apps using the CLI and the following command :

```
ng new <projectName>
```

Both of the apps give me a warning on GitHub:

> We found a potential security vulnerability in one of your
>   dependencies.
>
> Only the owner of this repository can see this message. Manage your
>   notification settings or learn more about security alerts.

When I check the security alert I see:

[image: security alert]

This is just a library / npm package that is auto-added to the template project.

I'm just learning the new Angular (8.1) and I'm not sure how or if I can remove that default library.

GitHub keeps auto emailing me about this warning and I'm trying to get it to stop.
I marked the notifications as read, but it warned me again.  Seems like it continues to do this. Do I have to remove the dependency for it to stop?

[image: notification read]

**What I've Tried**

I just attempted to remove the lodash dependency simply by deleting the dependency and attempting a rebuild but of course the project requires it and I get an error.  Just testing to see if the Angular Template project really does need lodash.

[image: remove dependency]

Comment: run `npm audit` it should provide you with details what to do, what to update etc.

Comment: @dallows I will try it now. thx.  Edit - tried it and npm reported: found 0 vulnerabilities
 in 19197 scanned packages  Edit 2 - npm v. 6.4.1

Comment: Your npm version is bit behind the latest. Honestly I'm not sure if it is possible that such version might ignore issues that GitHub consider as serious. Maybe updating npm might help?

Comment: @dallows I just noticed that too and updated to latest -6.10.1 and npm audit still reports 0 vulnerabilities.  Also, the real question I think is why does Angular (8.1) include a library that GitHub thinks has vulnerabilities?

Comment: It can happen, you are using some module which is marked as vulnerable and you might end up waiting for its creator to update it. Until then, your project/package is deemed as vulnerable also. Happened to me recently, getting same emails from GitHub,

Comment: @dallows That does make sense. My point is that it is the Angular template that includes it so every dev who creates an Angular project using ng new <projectName> and checks into GitHub will experience this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm keeps track of indirect dependencies in package-lock.json (yarn used yarn.lock).

When you created your Angular-project initially, the most recent version of lodash was picked and added to package-lock.json.

Indirect dependencies are locked in order to ensure that you (or someone else) get the exact same versions everytime `npm install` is called. Otherwise things may work on your computer, but fail for no obvious reason on the computer of a fellow developer.

But now there is a newer version of lodash, which fixes a security vulnerability. However, the very idea of locking indirect dependencies is to ensure that you will get the exact same version everytime.

If you create a new angular project today, you will end up with the fixed lodash version 4.17.14.

To fix you existing project, please run `npm install lodash@^4.17.14`

Comment: I was just running through that myself.  Very good catch.  You are correct on it having an older version of lodash and the new version was just published 5 days ago or something. I had created my project 5 or 6 days ago.  This is the definitive answer. Thanks!